# How do add "Recent Folders" item to the Finder sidebar?

Tags: finder

In the menu Go > Recent Places you can get a list of recently accessed folders. I want to add this to the Finder sidebar, but I am not seeing any clear explanation of how to do this.

Comment: I have this question as well, and as of Feb. 2019 have found no good solution.  I've tried various Spotlight commands (saved as "smart" folders, or using the mdfind command), and none seems to be able to work consistently.  Folders that I've used recently are often missing.  I've made unsuccessful attempts at this every year or so for the last few years.  Nothing seems to be able to reliably reproduce the functionality of Finder's "Recent Folders" menu item.  Very frustrating.

Comment: The only "solution" that I have personally found was using a different file manager. Path Finder has what you're looking for, it's not so polished but it has ton of features.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use a smart folder.

1. Right click the Finder in the Dock
2. Select New Smart Folder
3. Press the plus button
4. Select kind.
5. Select Last Modified/Opened or whatever you want.
6. Select 'This Mac'
7. Save your smart folder. When saving, make sure 'Add to Sidebar' is checked. Name your smart folder and you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. However I am wondering how the "opened in the last x days" part works. If I set it for 3 days, but then do not use my Mac for a week, will this come up empty (e.g. no 'recent' folders)? A more numeric approach such as "the last 20 accessed folders" is closer to what I had in mind. Also I was hoping to have the folders themselves directly listed in the sidebar; is that not possible?

Comment: It will likely come up empty if you abandon the Mac longer than the set date, and no, I am not aware of any way to make the folders themselves show up.

Comment: @user5359531, In your comment you said, "_Also I was hoping to have the folders themselves directly listed in the sidebar; is that not possible?_"... do you seriously want to add individual folders for each Recent Folder to the Sidebar? That could add up to 10 more objects under FAVORITES, are you sure you want that vs having a Recent Folder object on the Sidebar that when clicked shows the list of folders? It's probably programmatically possible however it's not so simple or straight forward due to how the information is stored. I've see an AppleScript that extracts the info and it's complex.

Comment: Yes that is actually exactly what I would like, a dynamic list of recently accessed directories in the sidebar. I am constantly jumping between the same half dozen at a time so it would be much more convenient than having to navigate a menu or parent directory every time. But in the mean time I will settle with the solution given here.

Comment: As of Catalina, this seems to pick up a ton of useless "_CodeSignature" and ".lproj" folders. Any tips on filtering them out? Removing "System files" doesn't seem to help. This sounds amazing if it works!

Comment: This method is ignoring a lot of folders that I've recently navigated to. I'm using Finder's Column View (Miller Columns); perhaps those folder views aren't registering as opens?

Comment: Actually, an answer is contained in this method. It turns out when you right click the Finder icon (in Carolina), it gives just the list of recently viewed folders the OP requested.

Answer (score 32):

Use spotlight to go to `finder` and then go to `preferences`. 
Go to `sidebar` option.
And check on the `Recents` checkbox.

Hope this helps you!

[image]

Comment: This does not apply to folders.

Comment: this is the right answer